# How can I encrypt my phone and computer

Tags: encryption

How do I make sure everything of mine is keep private? Everything from what I search to passwords to Facebook to banking? I'm pretty sure I've been hacked in the past considering I can no longer get into my old accounts

Comment: Your title and your post's body are not related. Your last line suggests that you actually have a completely different question than what you've asked.

Answer (score 1):

## Storage Encryption

- **I'm sorry.** Encrypting the storage of your devices won't change anything about your internet activity.
- Encrypted data has to be decrypted before you or your device will be able to access it. Every time.
- This means that encrypted devices are just as insecure as it was without encryption if stolen while powered on and unlocked.
- Nothing about this encryption of device storage will have **any effect** on your online security or privacy.
- Encrypting storage will *only* make the contents of that device harder to access **if** someone should gain **direct physical access** to the device while locked.

## Online privacy

**True** privacy is **almost** impossible online.

- Your searches have to be readable by the search engine.
- If you submit an unintelligible (encrypted) search query, your only results will be ones containing similarly unintelligible data instead of what you want to find.
- Google/yahoo/duckduckgo can't perform useful searches unless you tell them what to look for.

### **Facebook** and **Google**

**Facebook** and **Google** are two of the worst big-tech companies to track your every activity around the web. Even those who never created profiles with FB/Google have shadow-profiles. Created solely to enable tracking and sale of ID/gathered info to anyone who pays.

## Tracking

- Logging in with Google/Facebook profiles will kill **any** / **all** attempts at online privacy/anonymity until you clear all browser data/cookies and change any other identifying data-points they can collect...
- The protective anonymity provided by VPNs/Proxies/TOR disappear when your browser still has Session/Ad/Tracking cookies from earlier when you load the first page containing tracking/social media/advertising content like scripts/widgets/buttons.
- Example: Facebook like/share/comment objects that are embedded on any site will track users and send user info back to FB. Logged in or not.

## For 100% security

- **For any data you don't want the entire world to see:**

  - Keep it OFF devices with networking/internet.
  - Never upload such data to **"the cloud"** (Google Drive, Dropbox, Picasa/Google Photos, iCloud, etc.)
- **The only way tech-companies can't use your phone to spy on you:**

  - Throw away your smart phone, get a dumb one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you lost your phone or computer recently or left them unattended? Do you think your credentials were stolen that way? Encrypting your phone/computer data at rest are for these risk models. It does not help at all if e.g.

- your device gets infected,
- someone gets to use it while unlocked,
- you type your credentials on a phishing site,
- you use weak passwords or
- you have a poor password hygiene.

Once you realize it is not a secret weapon against everything, it actually is a good idea to encrypt data at rest. However, the *how* depends entirely on the device and its operating system.